# Replay for finding probability density function of a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, density-function

This is a re-question with maybe another view on [finding probability density function of a conditional expectation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148390/finding-probability-density-function-of-a-conditional-expectation) for same "**a)**".

That is, which one is the density function of a conditional expectation?

The answers there have stated that density of $E(X|Y)$ is just $f_Y(y)$. Is that a general true?

I mean, as stated
$$
 \begin{align} Z=E(X|Y) & \Rightarrow P(Z(Y) = z) = P(Y = z^{-1}(z)) = P(Y = y(z)) \\
& \Rightarrow f_Z(z) = f_Y(y(z)) \end{align}
$$
for the particular case, the density of $Z$ should be $f_Y(y)$, always?

Related question: Is $E(X|Y)$ a bijection from $Y$ to $Z$?

Thanks.

Comment: The density of conditional expectation is $E[X|Y=y]=\int xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$. I don't think your claim that $f_{E[X|Y]}=f_Y$ is true. 
http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf

Comment: @M.Nestor The claim is actually that $f_{\mathsf E(X\mid Y)}(z)=f_Y(y(z))$ for some *function* $y(\;)$ where $Y=y(Z)$.  Which holds *when* $y(\;)$ is a bijection from the support for $Y$ to that for $Z$, *and* $f_Y(\;)$ is a probability *mass* function for the discrete random variable $Y$.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comment. The question is not really how to evaluate $E(X|Y)$ but the density function of this random variable $Z=g(Y)$.

Comment: It turns out I misread things. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Related question: Is $E(X|Y)$ a bijection from $Y$ to $Z$?

No.   $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ *is* $Z$.   However, as such, $Z$ is measurable on the $\sigma$-algebra for $Y$.

It is not *generally* the case that there will be a bijection between *the support for the probability mass function* of $Y$ and that of $Z$.

So when $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)= g(Y)$ for some function $g$ which *happens to be* a bijection on the support for the probability *mass* function of $Y$, then: $$\mathsf P_{g(Y)}(z)=\mathsf P_Y(g^{-1}(z))$$

This does not work when $g$ is not invertable.